# How to add a nested object as a JavascriptInterface in Android?

Tags: java, javascript, android

I need to call a website that has some javascript in it in a `WebView`. The javascript calls a method in a nested object like this:

```
window.plugins.anObject.method();
```

and I need to intercept that call to `method()` and do something, when its called (i.e. a native implementation for `method()` in Java). Without that `plugins`object, I would just do

```java
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object() {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void method() {
        // yay!
    }
}, "anObject");
```

but as I wrote, `anObject` must be a child of another `plugins` object. So what I tried was to replace `"anObject"` by `"plugins.anObject"` but that doesn't work. Is there any way how I can achieve this?

Comment: I know this is super old post, did you manage to find solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instand of use:

```
window.plugins.anObject.method();
```

may be you can try this:

#### webview code:

```
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object() {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void anObject() {
        return new Object(){
             @JavascriptInterface
             public void method() {
                 //yay!
             }
        }
    }
}, "plugins");
```

#### js code :

```
window.plugins.anObject().method();
```

#### Note:

the NPObject return to your js is not a common javascript object at all,you can't iterate this object and you can't redefine your member function when you define in webview such as bellow:

```
$(function(){
var old_method = window.plugins.method;
window.plugins.method = function(){
    //do some thing
    old_method();
    //do another thing
};
});
```

Comment: If I was able to change the actual JS call, I would have done that right away.

Comment: @ohcibi the frontend side need to do some special change,may be you can set a special user-agent string in your webview and in your server side you can figure out it's from APP or browser,so you can out put some special stripts to APP